# Web preview equivalent in elastic beanstalk AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Does elasticbeanstalk have a same feature as web preview in aws amplify?

How can I deploy my PRs to elasticbeanstalk automatically to test if it is working properly?

Comment: CodePipeline integrates with beanstalk.

Comment: yea. but for every Pull request, i need to set up a new environment to run a test on it if i use code pipeline. Im looking for a way to automate it

Comment: Add CloudFormation actions that will create the new EB env for you each time you run your CP.